# Fix broken cross-references in a PDF

Tags: pdf

I downloaded a PDF online whose url is :
https://spada.uns.ac.id/pluginfile.php/196559/mod_resource/content/1/Douglas%20C.%20Montgomery%20Applied%20Statistics%20and%20Probability%20for%20Engineers%203ed.pdf

However, the cross-references which are highlighted in boldface do not work, neither in the TOC nor in the book flow). Is there a way to fix them without knowing or having the pre-compiled (word or latex for instance) version of the text available ? I saw threads using editors such as notepad to open PDFs and look for the "xref" and other related beacons but I am not sure how to proceed.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: This PDF has a stack of non-compliant remote file references, which may be causing a problem. Something to try, to repair this, on a 'Nix system: `sed -i 's,/FileSpec,/Filespec,g' /tmp/Douglas\ C.\ Montgomery\ Applied\ Statistics\ and\ Probability\ for\ Engineers\ 3ed.pdf`

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I will try the bookmark solution then as they indeed (partially) already work. Special thanks to @K J for the provided pieces of information !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the way out of date PDF file, is possibly a broken copy since it does not have the full set of supplementary corrections and other data for that very old version 3 as shown here.

https://bcs.wiley.com/he-bcs/Books?action=contents&itemId=0471204544&bcsId=1595

The best action would be to replace that 3rd Edition with an updated copy from the Author and I believe that is now 7th Edition with videos etc.

https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Applied+Statistics+and+Probability+for+Engineers%2C+7th+Edition-p-9781119400363#companion-sites-section